# key/value pairs in jcombo box

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, key-value-coding

relitivly simple i hope, i'm trying to set up a key/value pair for a jcombobox (swing). The display names are to mecurial to use as my check condition and are loaded from a array anyway so i need to find a way to load into the jcobo box a fetchable value for the ActionPerformed method and a display of the Keyvalue pairs. 
I'd rather like to avoid "fetching combo box value, loop through 75 index array to find a match (since the combo box values are loadied from the arry there would be exact matches) to get index of match. Update selected indexs array mutator with the new number." but right now it's the only viable solution

Comment: Here is simple key/value example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010537/java-swing-jcombobox-is-it-possible-to-have-hidden-data-for-each-item-in-the-l/5010548#5010548

Comment: That was perfect THANKS, it took a bit of modifying but did exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

**The basic concept to use is [ListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html).** Your combobox model  could be filled with your custom objects and the renderer would know how to represent each object. More information on combobox renderers could be found at

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer